# SuiteCRM integration with outlook

Tags: outlook, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I am new to SuiteCRM and want to integrate it with MS Outlook. So that when email will send through outlook it will save mail in history of SuiteCRM.

I have searched for it a lot but could not find any solution. Is there any plugin for it? Anyone have idea?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a plugin. SuiteCRM just released it, check their website:
https://store.suitecrm.com/addons/SuiteCRM-official-outlook-plugin?tag=suitecrm
There are several more plugins on their webshop.